# In Scala, Is it possible to build up a collection of partial functions into a function by iterating over a ListMap?

Tags: scala, recursion, dry, partialfunction, ordered-map

Yesterday, @Krzysztof Atłasik helped me figure out how to reduce redundancy in matching by using partial functions, so what used to look like:

```
  i match {
      case x if x == 0 ⇒
        romanNumeral

      case x if x >= 1000 ⇒
        this.roman(i - 1000, s"${romanNumeral}M")

      case x if x >= 900 ⇒
        this.roman(i - 900, s"${romanNumeral}CM")

      // etc.
```

now looks like:

```
object RomanNumerals {
  def roman(i: Int)(implicit romanNumeral: String = ""): String =
    this.tryRoman(romanNumeral)
      .orElse(this.tryRoman(1000, "M", romanNumeral))
      .orElse(this.tryRoman(900, "CM", romanNumeral))
      .orElse(this.tryRoman(500, "D", romanNumeral))
      .orElse(this.tryRoman(400, "CD", romanNumeral))
      .orElse(this.tryRoman(100, "C", romanNumeral))
      .orElse(this.tryRoman(90, "XC", romanNumeral))
      .orElse(this.tryRoman(50, "L", romanNumeral))
      .orElse(this.tryRoman(40, "XL", romanNumeral))
      .orElse(this.tryRoman(10, "X", romanNumeral))
      .orElse(this.tryRoman(9, "IX", romanNumeral))
      .orElse(this.tryRoman(5, "V", romanNumeral))
      .orElse(this.tryRoman(4, "IV", romanNumeral))
      .orElse(this.tryRoman(1, "I", romanNumeral))
      .apply(i)

  private def tryRoman(romanNumeral: String = ""): PartialFunction[Int, String] = {
    case value if value == 0 => romanNumeral
  }

  private def tryRoman(
                        upperGuard: Int,
                        token: String,
                        romanNumeral: String
                      ): PartialFunction[Int, String] = {
    case value if value >= upperGuard =>
      this.roman(value - upperGuard)(s"$romanNumeral$token")
  }
}
```

Okay, it is more concise and considerably drier, but I'm thinking I'd like to take this even further.

I've put all my values into a ListMap, like:

```
  val romanNumeralByValue: ListMap[Int, String] = ListMap(
    1000 → "M",
    900 → "CM",
    500 → "D",
    400 → "CD",
    100 → "C",
    90 → "XC",
    50 → "L",
    40 → "XL",
    10 → "X",
    9 → "IX",
    5 → "V",
    4 → "IV",
    1 → "I"
  )
```

Now, I am trying to figure how how to transform this map into the series of parial functions.

I thought it would be something like:

```
 def roman(i: Int)(implicit romanNumeral: String = ""): String = {
    romanNumeralByValue.reduce(tryRoman){
      case (keyvalue, accumulator) ⇒
        accumulator
          .orElse(this.tryRoman(keyvalue._1, keyvalue._2, romanNumeral))
    }.apply(i)
  }
```

But this doesn't compile.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: I did not downvote and I am with you that explained downvotes are more helpful than anonymous ones. But maybe this explanation helps with your frustration. It explains that anonymous downvotes are appreciated as well, since people make the sad experience of retaliatory downvotes. https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: I agree retaliatory downvotes are a sad thing; I don't see how their existence helps anyone at all since it just means that potentially useful or interesting information from someone who is somehow unliked gets buried.

Comment: I assume that this is just an exercise in learning how to handle/manipulate partial functions, because there are much smaller/simpler ways to go from integral value to Roman numeral.

Comment: @jwvh.  Yes, pretty much it is just an exercise.  At first I just wanted to convert to Roman numerals for an online coding challenge....  Now I want to see how DRY I can make this and explore what Scala can do.    I'm curious what you think would be a smaller/simpler way if you'd like to share, but that would not answer this question.

Comment: This should compile and run as-is, but adding `\n`s and more spaces will improve readability: `val grid=Array(Array("","M","MM","MMM"), Array("","C","CC","CCC","CD","D","DC","DCC","DCCC","CM"), Array("","X","XX","XXX","XL","L","LX","LXX","LXXX","XC"), Array("","I","II","III","IV","V","VI","VII","VIII","IX")); def intToRoman(num:Int):String={val str=f"$num%04d";(0 to 3).map(x=>grid(x)(str(x)-'0')).mkString}`

Comment: @jwvh, Cheer!  Very interesting approach!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the basic idea of how to build the function.
*(You still need to adapt this to your use case)*

```
def checkLowerLimit(lowerLimit: Int, result: String): PartialFunction[Int, String] = {
  case value if (value >= lowerLimit) => result
}

val limits: ListMap[Int, String] = ListMap(
  10 -> "ten",
  0 -> "zero"
)

val foo: PartialFunction[Int, String] =
  limits.map((checkLowerLimit _).tupled).reduce {
    (acc, f) => acc.orElse(f)
  }
```

Which you can test like:

```
foo(11)
// res: String = "ten"

foo(10)
// res: String = "ten"

foo(3)
// res: String = "zero"

foo(-1)
// scala.MatchError: -1 (of class java.lang.Integer)
```

---

### Edit

Applying the technique to the problem.

```
import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap
import scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder  

object RomanNumerals {
  private val romanNumeralByValue: ListMap[Int, String] = ListMap(
    1000 → "M",
    900 → "CM",
    500 → "D",
    400 → "CD",
    100 → "C",
    90 → "XC",
    50 → "L",
    40 → "XL",
    10 → "X",
    9 → "IX",
    5 → "V",
    4 → "IV",
    1 → "I"
  )

  private val tryRomanStep: (Int, String) => PartialFunction[Int, (Int, String)] =
    (upperLimit, result) => {
      case value if (value >= upperLimit) =>
        upperLimit -> result
    }

  private val tryRoman: PartialFunction[Int, (Int, String)] =
    romanNumeralByValue.map(tryRomanStep.tupled).reduce {
      (acc, f) => acc.orElse(f)
    }

  def roman(i: Int): String = {
    @annotation.tailrec
    def loop(remainingValue: Int, acc: StringBuilder): String =
      if (remainingValue == 0)
        acc.result()
      else {
        val (removedValue, newToken) = tryRoman(remainingValue)
        loop(remainingValue - removedValue, acc.append(newToken))
      }

    loop(
      remainingValue = i,
      acc = new StringBuilder()
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Cheers for the prompt response, but I'm afraid my Scala/Partial Function skills are not yet up to the task of adaptation here... whatever I try, the IDE complained about either `map((tryRoman _)`, `.tupled` and/or `.orElse`  ... Furthure assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: FWIW, this answers the title of the question, but not the detailing where additional parameters and/or recursion seems to make this more complicated.  (I'm currently debating whether to accept this answer and create a new question or just to modify my subject to be more nuanced...)

Comment: @BrianKessler Sorry, yesterday I post this just before turning down my pc. Please see the edited answer.

Comment: Don't worry about it!  Cheers for the revised answer!  I'll test it when I get home and accept once the answer is confirmed.  :-)   (It is interesting to note that it looks in this instance as maybe the cure is a little worse than the disease as it adds much more complexity than I anticipated.

Comment: @BrianKessler the good thing is that making changes is way more easy. However, the Roman numbers doesn't change too much lately... I wonder why.

Comment: Awesome job!  Now I need to wrap my head around it.    :-)

Comment: Okay, I think I more-or-less understand it... Do I correctly understand that every time the function is called, the chain of partial functions needs rebuilt?  I'm wondering if I can fix that.  ;-)

Comment: @BrianKessler No, the chain of functions is built and reduced just one time. And the final function is reused for consequent calls.